# Logging when cisco switch restarts, shuts down, or starts up

Tags: logging, syslog, cisco-catalyst

Is it possible to log events like restart,shutdown and start in cisco catalyst 3750. Also need to log when a new user is created. I'm forwarding the logs from the cisco switch to the syslog server and is able to obtain the login failure and success logs. I require the switch startup, shutdown, restart, creation of new user and software up-gradation logs to be forwarded to the syslog server. Is there any workaround or configuration for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to check at what logging level your device is configured to run. Step-by-step information on configuring logging message levels and types is available [here](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst3750x_3560x/software/release/12-2_53_se/configuration/guide/3750xscg/swlog.html#wp1028274).

Comment: My device is configured to run at level 5 (notification). But it's not logging when the switch shutdown/restart, create user, change password to the syslog server.

Comment: Try setting your "logging trap" level to 7 (debugging). This setting controls the messages logged to syslog servers. You might get a lot of noise out of this, but you can quickly determine whether the logs you need are included in it. Steps to set the logging trap level are outlined in the _"Defining the Message Severity Level"_ section in the link I shared.

Comment: ok let me set the logging trap level to 7 and check whether my requirement is satisfied. Info was useful.